# iPhone - Slow scroll on TableView

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, scroll, cell

i've problems with the scroll of my Table View. I have a custom cell that i load with this code :

```
if (cell == nil) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellQuartieri" owner:self options:NULL];
    cell=customCell;
}
```

This is the code. customCell is an UITableViewCell object with a own xib. The controller of the xib is my view controller where the table is placed in. I load 2 label and one imageView from the internet. What is the problem? And how can i make my custom cell reusable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that images have to be loaded asynchronously. Search SDWebImages on Google.

Answer (score 1):

To make your custom cell reusable, set the identifier propertie in Interface Builder.

Who do you load the data from the internet (Async)?

Comment: After block if( cell==nil) { ... } i load the image data.

Comment: Loading the data from the internet directly after the if (cell == nil) method will block app until all data is loaded from the internet. Search the web on Asynchronous loading of images.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a custom `UITableViewCell` you have to set the identifier string property through Interface Builder, and then dequeue the cell in the usual way, using that same string as the key. This way your app will not create a new cell for each row of the table, but will reuse the already present cells, reducing build and presentation times.

If this won't fix the issue, you should look at the internet connection, to understand why data loading is so slow. If you own the server that serves the data, you would try to speed it up, otherwise you should look for a different or more efficient way for loading data remotely. Some code example would be great.

#### Edit

As stated in the comments, the slowness could be related to the loading time of remote images. You could try to build a local dictionary, of something similar, in which you'll save the images you already loaded associating them to their URL as the key, while you'll read remotely those you still don't own. This will work like a local cache to improve loading time for remote data.

Comment: The code is simple : i have an url saved in Core Data and i pass this url in this way : imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:myObject.photo]]] where photo is the string ( url ) i saved in Core Data.

Comment: Then the slowness could be related to the loading time of remote images. You could try to build a local dictionary, of something similar, in which you'll save the images you already loaded, while you'll read remotely those you still don't own. This will work like a local cache to improve loading time for remote data.